# opening a url from a webpage automatically

Tags: html, arduino

I have created a web page for controlling a led using arduino.Now I want the web page to automatically open a url in the same tab if some condition is satisfied.I want the code for the above mentioned problem.Thanks

Comment: `window.open("www.youraddress.com","_self")` using js

Comment: Is that "condition satisfied" on the web server side and you need to send a redirecting HTTP response, or will the website have to "redirect itself" from within Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

3 possible ways are described below:

---

### Send HTTP response:

You can use HTTP response to redirect user to different page such as:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://google.com
```

I would go with this one as it requires the smallest amount of bytes to send from Arduino

---

### Send HTML code:

When your condition from arduino is met, you can output following code in HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="URL=http://google.com" />
```

and it will redirect you to Google.

---

### Send Javascript code:

When you want to recirect, use Javascript to do it:

```
window.location.href = 'new_link';
```

Comment: If you're doing this from within Javascript, there are better ways. If you're doing this from the server, there are *much* better ways. This is one of the worst ways to redirect a page.

Comment: Well, Arduino is not apache server. This is the easiest way to implement it there. It is not eveerything in software. If you want to write software, you need to know hardware. Arduino is not for what you think. It can, of course send HTTP redirect header but it will fail.

Comment: Frankly, I don't know anything about Arduinos, but if it has *any* server-side code (which I assume if it's anything more than a static web server), it *should* be able to set an HTTP header, no?

Comment: How will it "fail"?

Comment: Yes, it should be and I've corrected (fullfill) my answer already!